# OpenCart Local Login

Tags: opencart, local

I have OpenCart on my laptop. There is a Bitnami file in my C drive and inside it is a file called "opencart-3.0.3.6-1". Inside this file are many files.

When I type this number into the address bar: 127.0.0.1:81, a screen comes up with Bitnami at the top and "Awesome! OpenCart is now installed." Underneath it says "Access OpenCart". When I click Access OpenCart, a page comes up with "Your Store" at the top and some random products like phones and monitors for sale. So this must be OpenCart on my laptop.

I don't know what to do next. I want to get to a dashboard or somewhere I can edit this page with my own products but I don't know how to get to there. When I type this "http://127.0.0.1:81/opencart/admin/" into the address bar, I get a login screen asking for username and password but I don't have a username or password. Can anyone tell me how I can acquire a username and password? Thank you!

Comment: Start here: http://docs.opencart.com/en-gb/introduction/

Comment: Hi, thank you. Can you tell me where I am in the journey. I think I have OpenCart installed on my laptop. I don't know where to start in the introduction...instructions.

Comment: I want to learn how to use OpenCart locally. I don't want to upload it to a webhost.

Answer (score 0):

When installing you should have seen a pre-installation check screen followed by a configuration screen, where you would be asked to enter the database name, database user, password etc, as well as choosing an administrator username and password.

If somehow you managed to install it without doing those things, then you need to open up your database using something like MySQL Workbench of phpMyAdmin and navigate to the user table (default oc_user). There you would be able to see the administrator user, password and salt. The password will be encrypted.

According to [this page](https://dreamvention.com/blog/3-easy-tips-how-to-recover-your-opencart-admin-password/) you can reset the password by following the instructions supplied. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try logging in with a pattern, something like (User: admin, pass: admin) or (demo/demo), if it was a ready installation, that might be it, otherwise you will have to access PhpMyAdmin, go to the database and find the user > edit table, add the new login name and new password (the password is MD5 encoded) and save.

Comment: Is the stored password merely the MD5 hash of the string? That feels odd (and unsafe) for a well-known system such as OC. Normally they will include an algorithm, a salt, and a complexity level too.